Horror movie where a group unleashes an evil spirit that jumps from person to person after they are killed
I remember a movie that came out between 2002-2010.
A group of people are at a house and accidentally unleash an evil spirit that jumps from body to body after being killed. I believe they were trapped in the house and could not leave. I seem to remember them opening a white trap door in a wall to let it out. There was also a scene in the basement where one of the possessed people is burned alive or electrocuted. There was also a women who locked herself in one of the rooms and wouldn't come out. I believe they had to go down into the basement several times to turn the power back on.
It's not:

The Damned
Dead Mary
Nine Lives
Death's Door


https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BodySurf

2012 film *Hold Your Breath kind of fits except they do get out the abandoned prison and the killer is actually picked up by breathing near the cemetary where he is buried.

Long Time Dead (2002) has a similar premise, but doesn't match the finer details.

Thanks for the reply! Those movies are very similar. I've searched Tubi, Plex and googled. It's amazing how many movies follow this trope.(Thanks for the link FuzzyBoots!)
